# Create a function to find a specific word in the title

Tags: php

I have the following title formation on my website:

It's no use going back to yesterday, because at that time I was... Lewis Carroll

Always is: The phrase… (author).

I want to delete everything after the ellipsis (…), leaving only the sentence as the title. I thought of creating a function in php that would take the parts of the titles, throw them in an array and then I would work each part, identifying the only pattern I have in the title, which is the ellipsis… and then delete everything. But when I do that, in the X space of my array, it returns the following:

was...

In position 8 of the array comes the word and the ellipsis and I don't know how to find a pattern to delete the author of the title, my pattern was the ellipsis. Any idea?

```
<?php
$a = get_the_title(155571);
$search = '... ';
if(preg_match("/{$search}/i", $a)) {
    echo 'true';
}
?>
```

I tried with the code above and found the ellipsis, but I needed to bring it into an array to delete the part I need. I tried something like this:

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
global $wpdb;

$title_array = explode(' ', get_the_title(155571));
$search = '... ';
if (array_key_exists("/{$search}/i",$title_array)) {
echo "true";
}
?>
```

I started doing it this way, but it doesn't work, any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: By the way, what you're calling "the reticence" is technically [an "ellipsis"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis), but most commonly just called "dot dot dot".

Comment: Does the ellipsii appear only once in the string?

Comment: @Martin yes. Only once

Answer (score 1):

If you use regex you need to escape the string as [preg_quote()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) would do, because a dot belongs to the pattern.

But in your simple case, I would not use a regex and just search for the three dots from the end of the string.

**Note: When the elipsis come from the browser, there's no way to detect in PHP.**

```php
$title = 'The phrase... (author).';
echo getPlainTitle($title);

function getPlainTitle(string $title) {
    $rpos = strrpos($title, '...');
    return ($rpos === false) ? $title : substr($title, 0, $rpos);
}
```

will output

```
The phrase
```

Comment: What do you mean by "when the ellipsis come from the browser"?

Comment: @IMSoP When used via CSS by https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Comment: The idea is sensational. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: To clarify to highlighted comment above: PHP processes the data on the server before it ever reaches the end user client browser, so if the browser changes the data PHP will never know about it. For that you need Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since you're working with regular expressions, you need to remember that `.` has a special meaning there: it means "any character". So `/... /` just means "any three characters followed by a space", which isn't what you want. To match a literal `.` you need to escape it as `\.`

Secondly, rather than *searching* or *splitting*, you could achieve what you want by [*replacing* part of the string](https://www.php.net/preg_replace). For instance, you could find everything *after* the ellipsis, and replace it with an empty string. To do that you want a pattern of "dot dot dot followed by anything", where "anything" is spelled `.*`, so `\.\.\..*`

```
$title = preg_replace('/\.\.\..*/', '', $title);
```